# Use appledoc to generate documentation for some particular classes

Tags: ios, xcode, appledoc

I have written a simple reusable control and on looking for a way to document its functions and properties, I found this useful tool named - appledoc.

I have created a demo project to show the capabilities of my control. Now when I use appledoc to genetate document, its creating the references for demo classes also. I dont want this. I'm expecting appledoc to generate documentation for my reusable class only. How could I do that?

My runscript is like this:

```
APPLEDOC_PATH=`which appledoc`
if [ $APPLEDOC_PATH ]; then
$APPLEDOC_PATH \
--project-name "MyControl" \
--project-company "Company Name" \
--company-id "" \
--output ${PRODUCT_NAME}Docs \
--keep-undocumented-objects \
--keep-undocumented-members \
--keep-intermediate-files \
--no-repeat-first-par \
--no-warn-invalid-crossref \
--ignore "*.m,AppDelegate.h,ViewController.h" \
--exit-threshold 2 \
${PROJECT_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}
fi;
```

Tried adding my `AppDelegate` and `ViewController` class in --ignore tag, but it doesn't seems working. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by repeating `--ignore` flags,

```
--ignore .m \
--ignore AppDelegate.h \
--ignore ViewController.h \
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes..That indeed helps.. It works. Do u know the reverse method. I mean, instead of ignoring the rest of classes, just include the required classes. Is there anything available in appledoc.

Comment: @HRM I think it picks up all the files unless you specify which ones to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I usually create a documentation only for my models, ignoring my PODS and all view controllers.

have a look how i set it up:

```
APPLEDOC_PATH=`which appledoc`
if [ $APPLEDOC_PATH ]; then
    $APPLEDOC_PATH \
    --project-name "My APP" \
    --project-company "My Company Name" \
    --company-id "" \
    --output "PATH DIR" \
    --keep-undocumented-objects \
    --keep-undocumented-members \
    --keep-intermediate-files \
    --no-repeat-first-par \
    --no-warn-invalid-crossref \
    --ignore ".m" \
    --ignore "Pods" \
    --ignore "*Controller.h" \
    --ignore "*Cell.h" \
    --explicit-crossref \
    --keep-undocumented-objects \
    --keep-undocumented-members \
    --use-single-star \
    --no-repeat-first-par \
    --no-warn-missing-arg \
    --no-warn-undocumented-object \
    --no-warn-undocumented-member \
    --no-warn-empty-description \
    --exit-threshold 2 \
    ${PROJECT_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}
fi;
```

i ignored all these files:

```
    --ignore ".m" \             #all my .m files
    --ignore "Pods" \           # All my PODS
    --ignore "*Controller.h"  \ # any controlers (a.k.a ViewController, TablewViewController, CollectionViewController )
    --ignore "*Cell.h" \        # Any cell (a.k.a UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewCell)
```